# Can't call google oauth with Javascript/Heroku CORS anywhere or Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, google-oauth, cors-anywhere

I need to use Google's limited input device sign in with a code on screen.
This isn't available to Web Applications so I have to use the Other type,  therefore I cannot set CORS so I have set up a proxy on Heroku using [this](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere).

This works fine:

```
curl https://xxxxx.herokuapp.com/https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code -H "x-requested-with: *" -d "client_id=xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=profile"
```

This returns and error: `invalid_request`

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
  console.log(this.responseText);
  var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  console.log(data);
}
xhr.open("POST", 'https://xxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('x-requested-with', '*');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
  client_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  scope: 'profile'
}));
```

And so does this:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var request = require('request');

request({
    uri: 'https://xxxx.herokuapp.com/https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code',
    body: querystring.stringify({
      client_id: 'xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      scope: 'profile'
    }),
    headers: {
      'x-requested-with': '*'
    },
    method: 'POST'},
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(error)
        console.log(response)
        console.log(body)
    }
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason you can't use Firebase.auth? ...Just an option.

Comment: Side note: the only effect adding the `x-requested-with` request header has is to trigger your browser to send a CORS preflight OPTIONS request before trying the POST request from your code. That Google API endpoint doesn’t require that request header, nor do anything with it. So is there some other reason you’re adding it? If the reason is to get your CORS Anywhere proxy to handle the request as expected, then it’s still unnecessary — because the CORS Anywhere code looks for *either* the Origin header or the X-Requested-With header, and your browser’s already sending the Origin header…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code for your XHR request to this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
  console.log(this.responseText);
  var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  console.log(data);
}
xhr.open("POST", 'https://xxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send("client_id=xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=profile");
```

That is, send a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request header, and a request body in the format `client_id=xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=profile`.

At least that’s what you must do if you want to emulate the `curl` request shown in the question — because that `curl` invocation causes the literal value of the argument to the `-d` option to be sent as the request body — `client_id=xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=profile` — with a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request header.

You can confirm that yourself by adding `--trace-ascii /dev/stdout` to the `curl` invocation and examining the trace that `curl` logs to the console.

In contrast, the code for the XHR request in the question as-is sends a request body in the format `{client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com", scope: "profile"}` with a `Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8` request header.

See too the [“Request device and user codes” section](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices#step-1-request-device-and-user-codes) of the related Google documentation, which also shows a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request header is needed.

Comment: Thats it! I also didn't realize that I needed to send the POST data as an encoded query string...